# Ruby on Rails 3, Passing Params?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, hash

I'm currently trying to get all of the Events made by a User in my Ruby on Rails app.

Rails version = 3.0.9
Ruby version = 1.9.2

```
User has_many :events
Event belongs_to :user
```

**admin_controller.rb: (Used for displaying the admin section of the app)**

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @topuploaders = User.find(:all, :include => :events).sort_by { |u| -u.events.count }.first(5)
    @topflyers = Event.all(:limit =>10, :order => 'viewcount DESC')
  end

  def users
    @users = User.all
  end

  def flyers
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def get_flyers
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The function **users** finds and displays all of the Users by name.
I am stuck on how to make a link to a page that will display all of the events created by a user.

I tried to use the:

```
def get_flyers
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

And then display the names of the flyers in the view, but this did not work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I am quite new hear so I'm not sure if I've given enough detail, so please bear with me.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simply modify your `get_flyers` function to

`@flyers=User.find(params[:id]).events`

Then, `@flyers` will contain an array of events for that user, which you can display from your view.

Comment: How would I then link to this from the view containing the list of users?

Comment: You will have to place this function in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`, then you can access it from any view.

Comment: I've tried this but I am getting an error message saying "Couldn't find User without an ID".

Comment: I am getting an error message "Couldn't find User without an ID". I am using the following code to link to the function:

<%= link_to "View Flyers", admin_get_flyers_path(user) %>

Comment: @Ammar: you should accept this answer and post another question: one question at a time

Comment: @apneadiving: Sorry, I'm new here :) I will do, thank you for the advice.